# ограниченный доступ в gitlab для QA

Tags: git, gitlab

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как лучше сделать. Есть в gitlab на бесплатном аккаунте репозиторий с ветками начального тестирования,промежуточного тестирования и master. Нужно предоставить доступ QA-тестровщику к коммиитам этих веток для учета протестированных коммитов и их наличия в разных ветках репозитория. Но есть обязательное условие чтобы доступа к файлам репозитория у этого QA не было.
- если дать QA уровень доступа "гость", то он вообще не видит коммиты веток
- если дать уровень доступа "репортер", то открывается доступ к файлам для QA, что недопустимо
В документации по доступу пользователей я не вижу как тонко настроить доступ QA только к коммитам веток https://gitlab.com/help/user/permissions

Comment: И в коммитах не должны быть видны изменения в файлах?

Comment: У гитлаба было апи. Я бы на любимом языке сделал небольшую страницу, которая бы все выгребала и отображала в удобном виде.

Comment: - Изменения в файлах QA видеть может, на видимость изменений блокировка доступа не нужна.

Comment: - через API делать выборку вариант, но я предполагал что можно будет предоставить каким-либо способом доступ с уже существующим решением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У GitLab каких-то дополнительных средств разгранечения доступа, кроме описанных в документации нет, так что такой доступ настроить нельзя.

Но мне видится вариант, который может Вас устроить.

1. Отправлять на почту сообщения о пуше в репозиторий [Emails on push](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/emails_on_push.html#enabling-emails-on-push). В этих письмах можно оставить только тексты коммитов.
2. Дать пользователю QA уровень доступа "гость".

Comment: спасибо, ценный совет для моей потребности в условиях gitlab